# working with a complex data array which includes j

Tags: python

I am trying to import my data set to analyze in python. My data are saved as x+yj where j denotes that it's a complex number. I managed to import the data but I need to find the mean of it. But it gives me an error of
`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'`
which is I think the array is identified as a string because of j and I am trying to perform a calculation on a string.
This is how I imported my array

```
laser1 =  pd.read_csv("laser only\\laser only 1.csv", delimiter=',',dtype='str')
laser2 =  pd.read_csv("laser only\\laser only 2.csv", delimiter=',',dtype='str')
```

I extracted each column as follows (say for the first dataset)

```
laser1 = laser1.values
lt1 = laser1[1:,0:1] 
phtl1 = laser1[1:,2:3]
fl1 = laser1[1:,3:4]
```

I need to find `(lt1+lt2)/2` but it's giving me the above mentioned error.
Any help on how to fix this would be much appreciated

Comment: Can you show a couple of example rows of the CSV files?

Comment: You use dtype='str', doesn't that mean that all values in laser1 and laser2 are strings, rather than (complex) numbers?

Comment: hi, I found how it works. @RoelandRengelink When I import the data I had to use dtype='str' because the data saved as x+yj where x and y are numbers but j denotes that its a complex number. So somehow python identified j as a string. I fixed that using `lt1 = laser1[1:,0:1].astype(complex)`.  That way the extracted columns are identified as complex numbers and I could perform the operation.